# google did not crawl for my new updated website and crawling old once on same URl

Tags: google-search-console, google-index, local-seo

I have my website from last 7 years. recently now I have updated and redesign with some different landing page. I have deleted all old data from server. And have done all index pages with fetching by google console. But still it display my old website sometime.

Comment: If you had a website up for 7 years, Googlebot will likely continue to crawl the URLs for it **forever**.  You can't just replace your website and expect Google to know what is going on.   Your reputation with Google is tied to those old pages.    You need a better SEO migration strategy than just taking the old site down and putting up something completely different.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if this satisfies your question.

Answer (score 1):

It takes time. Google index is huge and the crawler must find out that a link is not valid by visiting it and seeing what return code it gets.

Once the crawler gets back either a Permanent Redirect (301) or Gone (410), then that URL will be marked for replacement or removal from the index. So the thing to do on your side is make sure you return these return codes whenever possible.

Using a Not Found (404) is less effective because Google can come back later and try to crawl it, in case it was a temporary malfunction.

EDIT: As @closetnoc commented. *Fetch as Googlebot* does not update the index nor does it force Google to update it any faster. It is a tool to help you see if there are any problems. The Google index is enormous and distributed around the world, so it takes time to update.

Comment: The OP mentions he is using Fetch as Google. This still takes time. It is not immediate. The regular googlebot comes back 1-2 days later and makes the change at that point. This feature has been abused over the years (of course) and therefore may not have taken the OP too seriously with multiple requests.

Comment: The OP should also update his sitemap files as well (if any) to prevent dead URLs from being referenced.